Why are my CSS animations not working on an AMP webstory page after a third-party script update?
I have an AMP page (webstory) that i developed with some css animations. I have noticed that what worked before (it was everything ok) now does not!
As long as we use third-part scripts i think somethin has changes since i have developed the solution that doesnt now allow css animations anymore.
Does anybody knows what has changed?
I have tested the css into a 'normal' html page and its ok. So the problem is not with my css.


body{background-color:red;}
.circles{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden
}
.circles li{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    animation:25s linear infinite animate;
    bottom:-150px
}
.circles li:first-child{
    left:25%;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    animation-delay:0s
}
.circles li:nth-child(2){
    left:10%;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    animation-delay:2s;
    animation-duration:12s
}
.circles li:nth-child(3){
    left:70%;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    animation-delay:4s
}
.circles li:nth-child(4){
    left:40%;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    animation-delay:0s;
    animation-duration:18s
}
.circles li:nth-child(5){
    left:65%;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    animation-delay:0s
}
.circles li:nth-child(6){
    left:75%;
    width:110px;
    height:110px;
    animation-delay:3s
}
.circles li:nth-child(7){
    left:35%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    animation-delay:7s
}
.circles li:nth-child(8){
    left:50%;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    animation-delay:15s;
    animation-duration:45s
}
.circles li:nth-child(9){
    left:20%;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    animation-delay:2s;
    animation-duration:35s
}
.circles li:nth-child(10){
    left:85%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    animation-delay:0s;
    animation-duration:11s
}
@keyframes steam {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 400% 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
 @keyframes animate {
     0%{
         transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
         opacity: 1;
         border-radius: 0;
    }
     100%{
         transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
         opacity: 0;
         border-radius: 50%;
    }
}
@keyframes cube{
    from{
        transform:scale(0) rotate(0) translate(0%,-5%);
        opacity:1
    }
    to{
        transform:scale(20) rotate(960deg) translate(-50%,-50%);
        opacity:0
    }
}
@keyframes cube{
    from{
        transform:scale(0) rotate(0) translate(0%,-5%);
        opacity:1
    }
    to{
        transform:scale(20) rotate(960deg) translate(-50%,-50%);
        opacity:0
    }
}
@keyframes gradient{
    0%,100%{
        background-position:0 0
    }
    50%{
        background-position:100% 100%
    }
}
@keyframes wave{
    100%,2%{
        transform:translateX(1)
    }
    25%,75%{
        transform:translateX(-25%)
    }
    50%{
        transform:translateX(-50%)
    }
}
 @keyframes animate {
     0%{
         transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
         opacity: 1;
         border-radius: 0;
    }
     100%{
         transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
         opacity: 0;
         border-radius: 50%;
    }
}
 @keyframes animate {
     0%{
         transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
         opacity: 1;
         border-radius: 0;
    }
     100%{
         transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
         opacity: 0;
         border-radius: 50%;
    }
}
@keyframes slide{
    0%{
        transform:translateX(-25%)
    }
    100%{
        transform:translateX(25%)
    }
}
 @keyframes animate {
     0%{
         transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
         opacity: 1;
         border-radius: 0;
    }
     100%{
         transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
         opacity: 0;
         border-radius: 50%;
    }
}
<ul class="circles">
                  <li></li>
                  <li></li>
                  <li></li>
                  <li></li>
                  <li></li>
                  <li></li>
                  <li></li>
                  <li></li>
                  <li></li>
                  <li></li>
               </ul>



I have noticed on browser console a new class loaded from the google js:
[template=fill]:not(.i-amphtml-story-grid-template-with-full-bleed-animation)>* {
bottom: 0 !important;
height: auto !important;
left: 0 !important;
position: absolute !important;
right: 0 !important;
top: 0 !important;
width: auto !important;}

